# Why the second initialization work while the first one fail because of the "element type does not match"?

Tags: c++

In c++ primer-initializing a Container as a copy of another container.

The element types in the new and original containers can differ as long as it is possible to convert the elements we are copying to the element type of the container we are initializing.

For example:

```
vector<const char*> articles = {"a", "an", "the"};
vector<string> words(articles) ; //error:element types must match
forward_list<string> words(articles.begin(), articles.end()); // ok, convert const char* to string
```

My question is why the second initialization work while the first one fail because of the element type does not match ?

Comment: [These](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) are the constructors defined for `std::vector`. Which do you think could match the second case? And which could match the first?

Comment: would that be the constructor that take single argument is explicit, so type conversion is not allow for initializing. While the constructors that second one used is not explicit, so type conversion is allow in this case ?

Comment: Actually, I should have linked the `forward_list` ctors as well as vector's ... time for an answer.

Comment: oops, didnt realize "these" is a link, that clarify my confusion anyways, thank you~

Comment: `forward_list` is a red herring, you could show the same behaviour using `vector<string>` in the last line

Comment: Er... Second one works, first one fails? Isn't it actually the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

The first line calls the constructor with an initializer_list of the same type as the element type ( const char*).
something like this:

```
vector<T>(initializer_list<T> t ) {....}
```

--> OK!

The second is a copy-constructor call which is only defined for the same element type.

```
vector<T>(const& vector<T> t) {...}
```

What you did is something like this:

```
vector<string>(const& vector<const char*> t){..}
```

--> Which does not exist!

Comment: That's exactly the reason. There's copy construction that works only for the same element type, and there is iterator range construction which can convert elements. The second line is neither.

Answer (score 0):

First line performs [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (cfr. [`initializer_list` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)).

Second line has [no matching constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) since the types don't match (it can't call a copy constructor).

Third line instead uses the [iterator range constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/forward_list) which *emplace-constructs* elements and has a viable `const char*` to `string` conversion to use.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why the second initialization works while the first one fails

You're constructing a *something*. This isn't done by magic, it just has to call one of the *something*'s constructors. Any expression which can't match one of the constructors, can't compile.

---

So, let's first consider

```
vector<const char*> articles = {"a", "an", "the"};
vector<string> words(articles);
```

Now, we need some `std::vector` constructor that makes sense with this expression. They're listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), and the only ones that come close to matching are numbers 5 and 6 (at the time of writing - they're the copy and move constructors).

The move constructor is out because we're not using `std::move` or otherwise working directly on an rvalue reference, so let's take a look at the copy constructor:

```
vector<string>::vector<string>(const vector<string> &other);
```

Note that this isn't templated to take any argument type, or to take a vector of any type: it only matches a const reference to a vector of exactly the same type. Even though `const char *` *is* implicitly convertible to `std::string`, the type `vector<string>` is still not the same as `vector<const char *>`. So, no constructor matches the argument type given.

---

Then, consider

```
forward_list<string> words(articles.begin(), articles.end());
```

The `std::forward_list` constructors are listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/forward_list). Note number 4:

```
template< class InputIt >
forward_list(InputIt first, InputIt last, 
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Firstly, this is templated on the iterator type, so passing `vector<string>::iterator` or `vector<const char *>::iterator` or whatever is no problem. Secondly, the conversion to `std::string` from `const char *` is sufficient for this overload to actually compile once it is selected.

---

Now, a couple of notes:

1. You mentioned the `explicit` keyword: this just prevents a single-argument constructor being used as an implicit conversion. It doesn't affect higher types though: even if `string::string(const char *)` is allowed as an implicit conversion, that doesn't make `vector<const char *>` convertible to `vector<string>`. That still has to go through one of `vector`'s constructors.
2. We're mostly talking here about how an overload (in this case an overloaded constructor) is selected. It's entirely possible the compiler can select an overload, and then still fail to compile. For example, using that second iterator range constructor, where the iterators point to some incompatible (not even explicitly convertible) type.

Comment: "Even if const char * were implicitly convertible to std::string" - it is. That constructor isn't explicit